# How to find out who using Sharepoint MySites in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, my-site

In firm we have got MySites turn on at Sharepoint 2013. How could I find out who using My Sites by powerscript in Sharepoint 2013, Or this is on Central Administration in GUI ? Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In additional to the answer of PowerShell:

[**My Sites**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/configure-my-sites) are just site collections for special usage, so they should all be listed under *Central Administration > Application Management > Site Collections > View all site collections*.

The user will be listed as Primary Administrator of his own My Site.

[image]

You can find the **My Site Host** via *User Profile Service Application > My Site Settings > Setup My Sites*.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

One line script to list all Site Owners for a web application (My Site Host):

```
Get-SPWebApplication "http://mysite.com" | Get-SPSite | Select Owner
```

And to export the list to Excel:

```
Get-SPWebApplication "http://mysite.com" | Get-SPSite | Select Owner | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\MySitesUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: But I want to list users who has using My Site. Not Users who has got My Site. It is need for Migration so we just want tio know wchitch site Should be migrated.

Comment: @GrzegorzZ Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, but @Chelsea_MSFT I don't need My Site administrators and owners, I need rto list a person who use a My Site. I don't need Owners who don't use this sites.

Comment: @GrzegorzZ But the Owner of the specific My Site is the user who is using My Site. If a user doesn’t use/have My Site, the My Site won’t be created at all.

Comment: Yes i know. But offen it is only clisc. And not do enything.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? What information do you need in detail? This gives you all the sites in the MySite webapplication (replace the URL to your MySite webapplication) with their URL, name of the owner and their Email.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

$arr = @()
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "https://mysite.com"

foreach($s in $wa.Sites) {
$arr += [pscustomobject]@{
    Url = $s.Url
    Owner = $s.Owner.DisplayName
    Email = $s.Owner.Email
    }
}

$arr | Out-GridView
```

Comment: I need  to have a answer who using something of MySite. And nothing more. If someone has got some fileson his My Site I need to write this person. And nothing more. I need list a users who using My Site. Not a Users who has got My Sites.

Comment: It is need for Migration so we just want to know wchich site should be migrated.